# Reading line from text file into C++ system() command

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and I'm trying to read a string from a text file that only contains one string and use that as input for a system() call. Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::string curlString = "/usr/bin/curl -O ";
    std::ifstream file("/Users/test/Desktop/test.txt");
    if (file) {
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline( file, line ));
    system(curlString + line);
    }
 }
```

This is probably a complete and utter mess, so thanks so much for helping out, I really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Why not build a std::string with the command that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the problem really is. Is it the reading from the file? There are planty of example how to do this in stackoverflow. Why do you not do something like:

```
std::string curlString = "/usr/bin/curl -O ";
std::string urlString= /* function that reads one line of code and does some verifcation if it is a URL */
system(curlString + urlString);
```

Comment: Hi ChaosCakeCoder, thanks for the reply. I think this is perfect, except on my system() line I'm getting "No matching function for call to 'system'". Sorry for the line questioning, I'm just totally brand new to C++. My original post has been updated with the code.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an awfully roundabout way to achieve your result.

There are a few easier ways to achieve this:

- you could build the string entirely in C++ by prompting the user there
- you could pass the string from Bash to C++ by sending it in as a command line argument in `argv`
- you could just call `curl` from `bash`

A file here just seems like overkill unless you have a specific need to create a file.

Comment: Hi nneonneo, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I have a specific need to create the file. It seems like passing the string from bash to C++ by sending it as argv might work in this case, I'll try that. And in this particular scenario, calling curl directly from the script fails, so I have to build it into the C++ binary that's going to be created.